# Generic List for two different List classes instead of List<dynamic>

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I am querying two different views based on some condition and it returns the collection and after that am using the collection to do some operation.

```
List<dynamic> query = new List<dynamic>();
            if (source == 1)
            {
                query = this.db.table1.Where(x => x.DATA_SRC_ID == source || x.DATA_SRC_ID == 3).ToList<dynamic>();
            }
            else if (source == 2)
            {
                query = this.db.table2.Where(x =>  x.DATA_SRC_ID == 3).ToList<dynamic>();
            }

            var result = query.Where(x => x.client_id == clientId).ToList();
```

if the view "table1" contains huge records means, converting to `list<dynamic>` degrades the performance. is there any other better way to do this ?. like some generic object should return from both if and else then i can use later in next.

below db context (using DB first approach in entity framework)

```
 private entities db = new entities ();
```

views/tables

```
table1
table2
```

instead of `List<dynamic>` how to decorate the list for two different classes.

Comment: Your possible classes should implement the same common interface (or base-class). Then you can simply build a list `List<MyInterface>`. Nevertheless: "list<dynamic> degrades the performance" Sais whom?

Comment: Since its an `if` and `else if`, why not put the `result = ...` inside both of them? Aside from making your code slightly longer, it becomes easier to understand & manage, and you can just use `var query = ...`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL yes you are right. But after getting the result i am doing lot of other stuffs too.

Comment: Why is the where clause on last line not part of the Where clause inside if else. This way, the filtering at last line is being done in memory, but if add that clause inside if/else, it would be done by database which could also help a little with performance.

Comment: Since you have decided that there is something in common between the two types, you put them in the same list, make it formal. Either inherit from the same base class for both types or implement the same interface. If you can't do either, consider wrapping both in a third and fourth object that again either inherit from the same base class or implement the same interface, and knows about the differences between the two actual objects.

Answer (score 4):

The most naive implementaion (not the best one) is to simply cast every item into the desired class making your list of type `object`:

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add(newInstanceOfA);
list.Add(newInstanceOfB);
```

Now you have to distinguish on the type of the current element:

```
foreach(var element in list) 
{
    var b = element as B();
    if(b != null) 
    {
        // do something with b
    }
    else 
    {
        a = (A) element;        // may fail if more types are possible
        // do something wit a
    }
}
```

Better would be if both classes implement the same common interface:

```
interface IMyInterface 
{
    void DoSomething();
}
class A : IMyInterface {}
class B : IMyInterface {}
```

Now you can easily create a new list:

```
var list = new List<IMyInterface>();
list.Add(newInstanceOfA);
list.Add(newInstanceOfB);

foreach(var element in list)
{
    element.DoSomething();
}
```

In your example you now could do something like this:

```
query = this.db.table1
    .Where(x => x.DNA_PGM_PRTN_ID == partitionId && (x.DATA_SRC_ID == source || x.DATA_SRC_ID == 3))
    .Cast<IMyInterface>().ToList();
```

Or

```
query = this.db.table2
    .Where(x => x.CLIENT_PGM_PRTN_ID == partitionId && (x.DATA_SRC_ID == source || x.DATA_SRC_ID == 3))
    .Cast<IMyInterface>().ToList();
```

repectivly.

EDIT: For abstracting fields into some common form you have to use an abstract class you inherit from instead of an interface making your list a `List<MyAbstractClass>`.

Comment: Yeap, if both classes share the same properties you could do so. If the properties are quite different and you can´t wrap them to anything common you should ask yourself why putting them into one list (remember: they reflect totally different things).

Comment: Since here we are mapping the fields, not any common function, therefore  abstract class would be better than Interface

Comment: @HimBromBeere consider total 5 properities are there common between both the classes if i put those 5 properities in interfacce, how can i access remaining properities outside the query

Comment: You can by explicit typecasting, provided you know which object is there inside

Comment: In addition to this this comes down to the first solution I´ve posted, however with at least of some abstraction through the interface, so it´s not *that* un-generic.

Comment: @HimBrom  you meant to create abstract class which contains all the properities of both the classes and use it in list right?  if both the classes contains 20 properties means if i put it in abstract class whether it will correct code practice?

Comment: No, you should make a class with properties for the *common* properties and those you can wrap into something similar. Ideally you´d have a base-class with only 10 members. However it might be usefull to give the members within the base-class a more common name (and even type if needed) then it is in the actual (derived) ones.